# Pandas - how to tell if data from a URL is in CSV or dictionary form before loading

Tags: python, pandas

I new to python and pandas. I am practicing with data from a URL and I am wondering, is there is a way to tell how the data is stored on the URL in order to load it correctly? I tried using type(df) but this doesn't provide the type of information I am looking for.

Comment: What do you mean by `how data is store` ?

Comment: `df.shape` will tell you the dimensions of the data being read into your dataframe. Or you can preview the data via `df.head()` and `df.tail()`

Comment: this isn't really anything to do with pandas...  use `requests` and `json()` / text of response